# SQL show available, reserved and cancelled seats

Tags: sql

Basically, I need to show the number of reserved , cancelled and available seats for a train.

I have this for the available seats:

```
 SELECT t.trainid, t.maxcapacity - coalesce(sum(b.numseats), 0) as availableseats 
FROM Train t
left JOIN TrainBooking b
ON t.TrainID = b.TrainID
WHERE b.Status IN ('r')
GROUP BY t.TrainID , t.maxcapacity
```

In the trainbooking table, I have a column called "status". Status is either reserved or cancelled. I need to display the reserved and cancelled seats with the available seats, but i'm not sure how to do this.

Example data of the  two tables:

Train:

```
TrainId maxseats 
1        10
2        10
```

Trainbooking:

```
bookingid  trainid status   numseats 
1            1      'r'       2
2            1      'c'       2
3            2      'r'       3
```

Results:

```
trainid availableseats  cancelledseats reservedseats
1           8                2             2
2           7                0             3
```

I'm new to SQL so any help would be appreciated - thanks.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following, here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dcyWq1mZe6n4bSdkSopu9J/2).

```
select
    trainId,
    (maxSeats - reservedSeats) as availableSeats,
    cancelledSeats,
    reservedSeats
from
(
  select
    t.trainId,
    maxSeats,
    sum(case when status = 'c' then numseats else 0 end) as cancelledSeats,
    sum(case when status = 'r' then numseats else 0 end) as reservedSeats
  from train t
  join trainBooking tb
  on t.trainId = tb.trainId
  group by
      t.trainId,
      maxSeats
) vals  
order by
    trainId
```

Output:

```
| trainid | availableSeats | cancelledSeats| reservedSeats |
| ------- | -------------- | ------------- | ------------- |
| 1       | 8              | 2             | 2             |
| 2       | 7              | 0             | 3             |
```

Comment: @Ncfc1 give it a shot and let me know if it won't work.

Comment: Sorry about the late reply. At the moment the available seats are calculated by subtracting the cancelled and reserved seats from maxseats. I only want the reserve seats to be subtracted.  There is also another problem with the available seats. For example, there are 3 reserved seats and 9  cancelled seats for a train. The max capacity for the train is 20. The answer should be 8  (currently it's subracting the reserve seats and cancelled seats as I said ) , but it is  giving me an answer of 15. I don't understand why.

Comment: @Ncfc1 are you saying that you want to subtract `maxSeats - (total of reserved and cancelled seats) `.  if yes then please look at here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/k4jqQETvapwkpAwcoZQ49B/0

Comment: @Ncfc1 but then how are you expecting answer `8` in your above example. it should be `17` then.

Comment: Yeah I was just using that as an example to show that it was giving me the wrong answer . I did it like that as  currently in my data base reserved and cancelled seats are being subtracted from maxseats -  just ignore that now .  However, I do want it to just subtract the reserved seats.  . Do I just use another case ?

Comment: @Ncfc1 try this one https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e2HxixdYAando1ChvduJ2w/0. If you like this please upvote the current answer. Thanks

Comment: Thanks -  I really appreciate your help. Sorry to ask you again  but I just inserted the data  (7,1,'r',2) into the trainbooking table. Trainid 1 still has maxseats of 10, so the new availabilty for trainid 1 should be 6 , but the answer it gave me was 16. This was the problem that I was trying to explain before.  This is an image of the database : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FvRg_zl_PUa-7UOsXGg_29XRQmcIYWJA

Comment: @Ncfc1 this should be good to go https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/w5vb3SrBEFrLC7Jjgc9P1d/0